# Communicate with USB printer serial port

Tags: java, linux, serial-port

I am trying to communicate with Edito (Seiko) KSM347 printer through Serial Port. I have successfully printed data through `echo "test" > /dev/usb/lp1` or Java's code:

```
FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("/dev/usb/lp1");
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fs);
ps.write(cmd); // cmd is bytes with corresponding commands
ps.flush();
```

It works properly too. But I need to send data and get response. In other projects I have been using RXTX library which was working good with for example Huawei MU609 modems. Now this library does not see these `/dev/usb/` ports.

```
CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
// this list contains only /dev/ttyS0 and /dev/ttyUSB0 devices.
```

How to force RXTX to use these ports? Even setting `-Dgnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts` does not work. Please help :)